# Checking if array is subset of other array. Java

Tags: java, subset

I have to make an array of 100 numbers and then shuffle the first 20 randomly to have 2 different arrays; A and B.

For this assignment I have to check wether the first 20 numbers from Array A are a subset of the first 20 numbers af Array B

Up until now I have this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class opgave6 {
 public static void main(String[] args){

  Verzameling a = new Verzameling(20, 3);
  Verzameling b = new Verzameling(20, 4);

  System.out.println(Verzameling.deelverzamelingVan());
 }
}



class Verzameling {
 int[] elementen;
 int elementen2;
 static int aantal2;

 Verzameling(int aantal , int seed) {
  elementen = new int[100];
  int aantal2 = aantal;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   elementen[i] = i;
  }

  Random random1 = new Random(seed);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   int r = random1.nextInt(100);
   int temp;
   temp = elementen[i];
   elementen[i] = elementen[r];
   elementen[r] = temp;
  } 

  printVerzameling(aantal);


 }

 Verzameling(int seed) {

 }

 void printVerzameling(int aantal){
  for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
   System.out.print(elementen[i] + " ");
  } 
  System.out.println();
 }

 static boolean deelverzamelingVan() {
  while (true) {
   for(i = 0; i < aantal2; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < aantal2; j++){
     if(Verzameling.a.elementen[i] = Verzameling.b.elementen[j])
     break;
    }
   }

  } 
 }


}
```

However, it doesnt work at all because I cannot figure out how to compare the elementen[i] from object A to element[j] from object B. How can i compare the different elements from both objects by using the static method in the same class.

(So Verzameling A and B are both instances of the Verzameling class, with a static method to check if A is subset of B. How can I get the numbers in the array from Verzameling A and B?)

If something is not clear please let me know! I don't need whole solutions, just how I can access the value of elementen[i] from object A and B. thanks!

EDIT:

this is the problem line:

if(Verzameling.a.elementen[i] == Verzameling.b.elementen[j])

thanks for the comment, however it is still erroring when i compile. It says it cannot find symbol about verzameling.a.elementen, i, verzameling.b.elementen and j. I think i am naming it wrong, is it ok to call the variable by saying: classname.objectname.variable of object?

Comment: thanks @ hvgotcodes for the layout edit, I never seem to get it to work? how do you do it?

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code?  Or type it in SO?  You shouldn't have a single `=`; it shuld be `==`.  But then, it wouldn't compile, so that probably doesn't help you.

Comment: @javaa, i used the code formatting icon in the editor -- its a bunch of 1s and 0s.

Comment: I am wondering why cant you use List.containsAll(...) and Arrasy.asList(....)

Comment: @Pangea: `Arrays.asList` doesn't work like you expect when given a primitive array. `List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(someIntArray)`

Comment: Should this be marked as homework?

Comment: thanks for the comment, however it is still erroring when i compile. It says it cannot find symbol about verzameling.a.elementen, i, verzameling.b.elementen and j. I think i am naming it wrong, is it ok to call the variable by saying: classname.objectname.variable of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your if statement is jacked up:

```
if(Verzameling.a.elementen[i] = Verzameling.b.elementen[j])
```

you are doing assignment, you are not testing anything.

try

```
Verzameling.a.elementen[i].equals(Verzameling.b.elementen[j])
```

or

```
Verzameling.a.elementen[i] == Verzameling.b.elementen[j]
```

note that you will need to make sure Verzameling.a.elementen[i] is not null if you use the equals method.  Also note that for numbers == is ok, but for objects you want to use equals unless you are sure you want == (== means something very specific for objects)

PREEDIT --

Your code is not compiling for a few reasons.  The first of which is that your a and b variables are declared in the scope of main, so they are only accessible in main.  Moving them up to the class and making them public and static means they can be accessed from anywhere.

EDIT -- I can't believe Im doing someone's homework, but -- this does not work, but at least it compiles

```
import java.util.Random;

public class opgave6 {
    public static Verzameling a = new Verzameling(20, 3);
    public static Verzameling b = new Verzameling(20, 4);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("before something");
        System.out.println(Verzameling.deelverzamelingVan());
        System.out.println("after something");
    }
}


class Verzameling {
    int[] elementen;
    int elementen2;
    static int aantal2;

    Verzameling(int aantal, int seed) {
        elementen = new int[100];
        int aantal2 = aantal;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            elementen[i] = i;
        }

        Random random1 = new Random(seed);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int r = random1.nextInt(100);
            int temp;
            temp = elementen[i];
            elementen[i] = elementen[r];
            elementen[r] = temp;
        }

        printVerzameling(aantal);
    }

    // you arent using it -- do so or delete it
    Verzameling(int seed) {
    }

    void printVerzameling(int aantal) {
        for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
            System.out.print(elementen[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static boolean deelverzamelingVan() {
        for (int i = 0; i < aantal2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < aantal2; j++) {
                int aElementen = opgave6.a.elementen[i];
                int bElementen = opgave6.b.elementen[j];
                System.out.println(String.format("Comparing a[i] to b[i] [%d, %d]", aElementen, bElementen));
                if (aElementen == bElementen)
                    break;
            }
        }

        // need to return something, i dont know what.
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, however it is still erroring when i compile. It says it cannot find symbol about verzameling.a.elementen, i, verzameling.b.elementen and j. I think i am naming it wrong, is it ok to call the variable by saying: classname.objectname.variable of object?

Comment: @javaaaa if the object is static and the variable is public

Comment: the object cant be static right? the method static boolean deelVerzameling is static, but objects cant be static per definition right?

Comment: it gives 10 error right now all to do with:

opgave63.java:64: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable b
location: class Verzameling
     if(Verzameling.a.elementen[i] = Verzameling.b.elementen[j])
                                                ^

Comment: @javaaaa you could make  Verzameling a and b public static properties on opgave6.  I put your code in my IDE and it had more problems than that though....

Comment: Thanks, but i dont understand what you mean. The thing is, when i would try to disply the 1st element of the verzameling a from the main method in opgave6, i just put System.out.println(a.elementen[0]);. However, when i call it from out of the method within the Verzameling class, this doesn't work. Why is that, and how can i make it work from out of the method within the Verzameling class?

Comment: to be clear: a.elementen[0] from main in opgave6 class does work, while it doesn't work within the method in the Verzameling class.

Comment: whoah! didnt see your big edit! First of all thank you a lot for making it work, your the best! You really didn't have to do that. However, i still don't understand .why. it didnt work previously. Why cant you refer to a element of a set by a.elementen[0] from within the class in a method? Why doesnt it work like that, and does when you make static publics within your main class?

Comment: @javaa i answered why moving a and b around made the code compile in the main answer.  Note that this code still is not working.  You need to do the rest.  Also, I think you have some code in there that is lingering around from earlier and is no longer relevant.  why dont you start over, taking the pieces that work?

Comment: Hey man, thanks very much I understand now! About the rest of the code that is floating around, some are things i'll have to fill up for the assignment and some are things to test whether what i have is working. Just trying to handle the assignment by making little sub problems and fix them first. anyway, loads of thats!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Verzameling.a.elementen[i] = Verzameling.b.elementen[j])
```

is assigning, not compaing. I suppose you want ==, but an evenbetter option would to override the equals()

```
if(Verzameling.a.elementen[i] == Verzameling.b.elementen[j])
```

or

```
if(Verzameling.a.elementen[i].equals(Verzameling.b.elementen[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Verzameling.a.elementen[i] = Verzameling.b.elementen[j]

should be:

```
Verzameling.a.elementen[i] == Verzameling.b.elementen[j]
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, however it is still erroring when i compile. It says it cannot find symbol about verzameling.a.elementen, i, verzameling.b.elementen and j. I think i am naming it wrong, is it ok to call the variable by saying: classname.objectname.variable of object?

Answer (score 0):

Sort each of the arrays, compare. Or better yet, put the integers into a set type, and check if one is a subset of the other. Look up the Set interface, use the containsAll() method.